# DataGrid only updating selected cell

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, wpfdatagrid

So i have fallen into a problem I am able to update values in a data grid when a textbox edits the value of the cell that the datagrid is selected on, this results in a UI update instantly. The pitfal is that i cannot update arbitrary cells that depend on this cell's value. The data in which the cell/column is bound to changes yet the DataGrid Doesn't update the depedent cells values. I have a lot of cells so it is very costly to call the DataGrid.Item.Refresh(). I have tried creating a method that just raises an InotifyProperty changed event yet this doesn't cause an update in the grid. I am at a loss as how to force the GUI to update.

The code for the model cell is below. and the biding code is below it.

```
public class ModelCell : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    //This is a class that represents a cell that a user clicks on. it contains few items. And should have a reference to the SpreadSheet object
    public String CellName {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public IEnumerable<String> dependents {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public String Contents {
        get {
            return Host.GetCellContents(CellName);
        }
        set {
            if (value != _contents) {
                IEnumerable<String> tmpDep = Host.SetCellContents(CellName, value);
                try {
                    if (Host.GetCellValue(CellName) is SS.FormulaError) {
                        //Revert the change.
                        Host.SetCellContents(CellName, _contents);
                    } else {
                        _contents = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("Contents");
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
                        //Next is to notify dependents that we have changed. Since the names will be in the Format of A1
                        this.dependents = tmpDep;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //We got an exception  no change was made to the sheet anyway. 
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                }
            } else NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public int Row;
    public int Col;
    public override string ToString () {
        return "THis is a test!";
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Default initialize the empty cell to empty contents. this makes the construction of the objects simpler;
    /// </summary>
    private String _contents = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// This value is contained in the SpreadSheet so it is automatically changed with the Contents.
    /// </summary>
    public String Value {
        get {
            try {
                Object returned = Host.GetCellValue(CellName);
                if (returned is String || returned is Double)
                    return returned.ToString();
                return ((SS.FormulaError)returned).Reason;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show("Cell " + this.CellName + " encountered an exception getting the value: " + e.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
        set {
            //instead assign contents
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
    public SS.Spreadsheet Host {
        set;
        private get;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an empty cell with no value or contents with the specified name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Name">The Name of this cell generally in the format [A-Z][1-99]</param>
    public ModelCell (String Name) {
        this.CellName = Name;
    }
    public ModelCell () {
        //Name will equal the base.ToString()
        this.CellName = base.ToString();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged (String propertyName) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public MainWindow () {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        DataGrid Sheet = null;
        if (this.FindName("Sheet") is DataGrid)
            Sheet = (DataGrid)this.FindName("Sheet");
        if (Sheet == null)//Exit
            this.Close();
        IValueConverter converter = new ModelCellConverter();
        Binding bind;
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            DataGridColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
            col.Header = (char)('A' + i);
            col.IsReadOnly = true;
            col.Width = new DataGridLength(60);
            col.CanUserSort = false;
            //bind = new Binding(new String((char)('A' + i), 1));
            bind = new Binding("indexAbleArr[" + i + "].Value");
            //bind.Converter = new IdentityConverter();
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            ((DataGridTextColumn)col).Binding = bind;
            Sheet.Columns.Add(col);
        }
        Sheet.ItemsSource = ViewModel.Rows;

        //Current cell display
        Label lab = null;
        if (this.FindName("CurCell") is Label) {
            lab = (Label)this.FindName("CurCell");
            bind = new Binding("ActiveCell.CellName");
            bind.Source = ViewModel;
            bind.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
            lab.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, bind);
        } //Don't bind the label if i cant find it
        if (this.FindName("ValueBox") is Label) {
            lab = (Label)this.FindName("ValueBox");
            bind = new Binding("ActiveCell");
            bind.Source = ViewModel;
            bind.Converter = converter;
            bind.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
            lab.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, bind);
        }
        TextBox content = null;
        if (this.FindName("Content") is TextBox) {
            content = (TextBox)this.FindName("Content");
            bind = new Binding("ActiveCell.Contents");
            bind.Source = ViewModel;
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            bind.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
            content.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
        }
        ViewModel.ActiveCell = ViewModel.Rows[0].indexAbleArr[0];
 }
```

I am using XAML To specify the Layout but no binding is done via XAML so nothing noteworthy is in my XAML code. Rows is a Object that contains an array of model cells (indexAbleArray) for the purposes of binding. It also precreates the 26 needed modelcells for the binding to not throw a million null pointer exceptions.

Comment: I am doing something similar.  But I am using GridView.  In a separate detail frame an update to a single value can change more than one value in the GridView and does show up.  I am not real familiar with ViewModel but I do know I had to bind the rows to an ObservableCollection to get it to work.  I would wire up a pass through converter so you can verify it called call and catch any errors.

Comment: I skip the binding to an ObservableCollection as I can bind directly to the values in the array, as they have InotifyPropertyChanged event. as i metioned eariler this technique works great for the singel cells being updated but not potential dependents.

Comment: But the Grid is bound to the collection!  You need a collection that forwards INotify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your portion of index based columns `indexAbleArr[" + i + "]` in the binding Path of your DataGridTextColumns. They are not participating in the property change notifications.

As BalamBalam suggested make that array into an `ObservableCollection` or you should be raising a property changed notification at row level for property "indexAbleArr" when any cell int that array changes it `Value`.

Both to me are actually incomplete designs. :(

Comment: I have tried rasing an event withing the Row object for all variations of IndexbleArr[i] ect. The confusion to my is why does the cell update when it has focus and not when it doesn't. its as if the data grid only listens for events on the selected cell.